# spark application in standalone mode with multiple master

Tags: apache-spark, high-availability, cassandra-2.1, apache-zookeeper, apache-spark-standalone

I created 1 application on spark. This application works as a http server and is combined with a cassandra db. 
In my case the application is running all the time on one master by the spark-submit command , with 3 slaves on 3 differents clusters.

I want to use zookeeper to have an high availability. 
Now i can launch a master in each cluster and if the server die , An other take the hand and become the master. It's perfect.
BUT, my problem is , what happen with my application. When the server die , it stop my application. 
Is it possible to keep alive my application when the server die? 
Did i miss something in the configuration?

Could you help me?

Thanks a lot for your future answer :)